# Board of directors

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A board of directors consist of Mr Koh, Mrs Ho and 7 other people. A committee consisting of 4 people is to be formed from this board of directors.

(i) How many committees can be formed if it must include both Mr Koh and Mrs Ho?

My answer:

$$ \binom{7}{2} = 21$$

(ii) Calculate the probability for the committee to include either Mr Koh or Mrs Ho but not
both.

My answer:

Number of ways to choose 4 members  $$ \binom{9}{4} = 126$$

Number of ways to choose both Mr Koh and Mrs Ho $$ \binom{7}{2} = 21$$

Number of ways to choose a committee not including both Mr Koh and Mrs Ho $$ \binom{7}{4} = 35$$

Probability of choosing either Mr Koh or Mrs Ho $$ \frac{126-21-35}{126}=\frac{70}{126}=\frac{5}{9}$$

The committee is formed and consists of Mr Koh, Mrs Ho and 2 other people. For a photograph, the 4 people need to stand in a line.

(iii) However, Mr Koh and Mrs Ho refused to stand next to each other. In how many ways can the committee members stand in a line?

My answer: 4P2 = 12

I would like to check if all my answers to (i), (ii) and (iii) are correct? Many Thanks

Comment: Hi. I believe all of the answers are correct. Number one is trivial, and I cross-checked 2&3 in different ways and got the same results.

Comment: Please explain your reasoning for the third problem.  While the result is correct, it is not clear to me why you are permuting two of four objects.

Comment: Same remark as NFTaussig. For first questions, you give many details, and the reeasoning is clear, and correct. For last question, you should explain why this formula. Maybe another option is to give a general formula, with a board of $n$ directors ($n=4$ in the example), because for small numbers, wrong reasoning may sometime reach to the correct number, only by chance.

Comment: And while you’re at it, I encourage you to choose a new title… one that describes the mathematics involved rather than a non-mathematical detail of the story.  This is the math stack exchange, not the corporate-governance one.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you have obtained the correct numerical answers to each question.  However, your reasoning for the third problem, which you have not explained, looks faulty.

> A board of directors consist of Mr. Koh, Mrs. Ho and $7$ other people. A committee consisting of $4$ people is to be formed from this board of directors.

> (i) How many committees can be formed if it must include both Mr. Koh and Mrs. Ho?

There is one way to select both Mr. Koh and Mrs. Ho and $\binom{7}{2}$ ways to select two of the other seven people.  Thus, there are indeed
$$\binom{2}{2}\binom{7}{2} = \binom{7}{2}$$
ways to select a four-person committee that includes both Mr. Koh and Mrs. Ho.

> (ii)  Calculate the probability for the committee to include either Mr. Koh or Mrs. Ho but not both.

Your answer and reasoning are both correct.

Here is another way to count the favorable cases.  We must select exactly one of Mr. Koh and Mrs. Ho, which can be done in $\binom{2}{1}$ ways, and three of the other seven people, which can be done in $\binom{7}{3}$ ways.  Hence, the number of favorable cases is
$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{7}{3}$$
Therefore,
$$\Pr(\text{exactly one of Mr. Koh and Mrs. Ho is chosen}) = \frac{\dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{7}{3}}{\dbinom{9}{4}} = \frac{5}{9}$$
as you found.

> (iii)  The committee is formed and consists of Mr. Koh, Mrs. Ho and $2$ other people. For a photograph, the $4$ people need to stand in a line.  However, Mr. Koh and Mrs. Ho refused to stand next to each other. In how many ways can the committee members stand in a line?

**Method 1:**  If there were no restrictions, the four people could be arranged in $4!$ ways.  If Mr. Koh and Mrs. Ho were to stand together, we would have three objects to arrange: the block containing Mr. Koh and Mrs. Ho and the other two people.  The three objects can be arranged in $3!$ ways.  Mr. Koh and Mrs. Ho can be arranged within their block in $2!$ ways.  Hence, there are
$$4! - 3!2!$$
arrangements of the four committee members in which Mr. Koh and Mrs. Ho do not stand in adjacent positions.

**Method 2:**  We can line up the two committee members other than Mr. Koh and Mrs. Ho in $2!$ ways.  Doing so creates three spaces in which to place Mr. Koh and Mrs. Ho, the left end of the line, the right end of the line, and the space between those two people.
$$\square P_1 \square P_2 \square$$
To ensure Mr. Koh and Mrs. Ho do not stand next to each other, we must place them in separate spaces.  We can place Mrs. Ho in three ways, which leaves two choices for Mr. Koh.  Hence, there are
$$2! \cdot 3 \cdot 2$$
arrangements of the four committee members in which Mr. Koh and Mrs. Ho do not stand next to each other.